# AngularJS $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, scope

I'm currently building a multilingual AngularJS app. All my data is retrieved from api which returns the correct languages. The problem is. Currently I'm using a `$scope` for every button, every thing in the app. Is this the best way or is there a way to call this directly from a view.

For example:

```
{{datakey.get.test}}
```

Some application specific info:

I get the data once (when loading the app) from the api. As a $http I currently retrieve the data and then for each scope I do this:

For example the select button:

```
$scope.selectButton = resourceKey.filter(function (item) {
    return item.name === prefix + "select-button"
})[0].value;
```

Then in the view I call `{{selectButton}}`

But the problem is. My controller is currently getting spammed with these kinda $scopes.

Can this be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys are all known and retrieved from an API, you can write a directive to do the replacement for you and won't have to clutter your scope. As an exercise, I've left variable arg replacement (e.g the {0} in "You have selected {0} items") unimplemented... In any case, you should avoid a watch when the value is static/doesn't change.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

// Mocking these out, assuming they would come from API and be set in
// key: value manner
.value('localeKeys', {
    'datakey.get.test': 'Testing 1',
    'datakey.select-button': 'Select'
})

// Simple lookup
.directive('appTranslate', function (localeKeys) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var attr = attrs.appTranslate,
             translated = localeKeys[attr] || attr || '';
            
            elem.html(translated);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <h3 app-translate="datakey.get.test"></h3>
    <button type="button" app-translate="datakey.select-button"></button>
</div>
```

The above sample simply looks up the value provided to the directive in the localeKeys. You would swap these localeKeys with the values you retrieve from your API.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use filter instead of directive:

```
.filter('translate', function (localeKeys) {
    return function(input) {
       return localKeys[input] || 'Missing translation for' + input;
    };
});

# View
{{ 'translation.key' | translate }}
```

Comment: Like it, but should add the one time binding. Filters have had some implication with performance issues, but this should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are fetching static data(you wont change button names), you can bind your button name in one-way binding avoiding the overhead, just use `::` this tells angular that DONT'N put a $watch over that expression to see if there is any change.

```
{{::datakey.get.test}}
```